# Python slice setting not O(n + k)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

The two statements below run in approximately the same time and I do not understand why.
The first inserts a new slice of length 1 into a list of length 100.
The second inserts a new slice of length 1 into a list of length 10000 and takes only 23% longer in time on my PC.

```
timeit.timeit(stmt = 'test[10:10] = [-1]', setup = 'test = [i for i in 
range(100)]', number = 100000)
timeit.timeit(stmt = 'test[10:10] = [-1]', setup = 'test = [i for i in 
range(10000)]', number = 100000)
```

Python wiki's [Time Complexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) says that the complexity of slice setting is O(n + k) where k is the length of the slice and n is the length of the list. That makes sense to me - everything after the inserted slice must be moved. So I expect the second statement to take 100 times longer.

When the list is longer (a million integers) then the behaviour is closer to linear with n as I expect.
So what is happening to make the short list slice setting only weakly depend on n?

Comment: There's some overhead associated with the other stuff on that line that's taking up most of the time (building `[-1]`, building the slice object).  As `n` increases it will overtake the constant costs, but for small `n` this isn't surprising.

Comment: Yeah I expect an overhead, but in order to double the time of the first statement the list has to increase to about 50000. So the overhead is equivalent to about 50000 operations, which seems unexpectedly large and implying that small list splicing is inefficient because of the overhead..